# How to find if a Column contains '%' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a created a table as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(CustomerID integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);

/* Added few records in this table */
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(1,'Tom');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(2,'Lucy');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(3,'Jenny%123');
```

Now, I have to find the Name which contains % in them.

I should get `'Jenny%123'`

The query I used is

```
SELECT * FROM Customer where Name LIKE '%%%';
```

But I'm getting all the rows. I just want the Name that contains % in it.

Comment: LIKE '%[^0-9\%]%' ESCAPE '\'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select *
from Customer
where charindex ('%', Name) <> 0
```

The above is, of course, *non-sargable*, but it's easier to understand IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `escape` clause to treat the middle `%` as a literal:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Name LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\';
-- Use escape character -----------------^
-- Define escape character -------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Customer where Name LIKE '%[%]%'
```

this will work

why store % in the first place?

Comment: Thanks PandePopo.